# The probability of mistake of randomized program.

Tags: probability

Consider this program to detect odd and even numbers:

- If the input number is even, it prints $even$.
- If the number is odd, it has a $4/5$ probability of printing $odd$ and $1/5$ probability of printing $even$.

How many times must the program run so that the probability of getting the correct answer is 0.99 (confidence).

**My solution**
If the program prints $odd$ then the number is certainly odd, because if it was even the program would print $even$. But if program prints $even$ there is a probability that the number is actually odd. So the probability of error is when it prints $even$ but the number is odd.

So using Bayes rule we have:

$$ P(odd | print\ even ) = \frac{P(odd \wedge print\ even) }{P (odd \wedge print\ even) + P(even \wedge print\ even)} $$

In this case we repeat the program until we either get an $odd$ or repeating $even$ for $K$ times. Is it correct? However I then don't know how to continue and what is the value for each of these components. You can assume the probability of a number is odd or even equal to 0.5

Comment: A big missing piece here is the probability of the input being even or odd. Can we assume it's equally likely to be even or odd?

Comment: First step is correct. As soon as "odd" appears we are done, the number cannot be even anymore. So, you just have to calculate the probability , given the output was "even" $k$ times , that the number is actually even. To finally use the Baysian formula, you can assume that the a priori probability that the number is even is $\frac{1}{2}$. Then, take the smallest $k$ giving a probability exceeding $0.99$

Comment: @Caedmon yes you can!

Comment: @Ahmad Please add this to the problem description

Comment: @Peter Thanks but I didn't get unfortunately, *the smallest k giving the probability (which probability??) exceeding 0.99*. If you check present answers each says something and they both seems correct. I would appreciate if you post your answer with more details.

Comment: @Ahmad I mean the conditional propbability that , given that "even" occured $k$ times that the number is even. This is more accurate than just using the probability that an odd number is detected odd within $k$ trials, of course this probability is far easier to determine.

Comment: @Peter thanks, all in all if you say what Caedmon gave in his answer, then I got his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track. This formula is correct:
$$ P(odd | print\ even ) = \frac{P(odd \cap print\ even) }{P (odd \cap print\ even) + P(even \cap print\ even)} $$

$P(odd \cap print\ even)$ would be mean that the input was odd, and mistakenly got switched to even. Since these events are mutually exclusive: $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{10}$

$P(even \cap print\ even)$ would just be $\frac{1}{2}$. If the input is even, it's guaranteed to be even.

Plugging these in we get: $$\frac{1/10}{1/10+1/2}$$

$ P(odd | print\ even ) = \frac{1}{6}$. As for the last step it's very unclear what you mean. What defines "correct answer"? The was I see it there's a chance at every step that the answer is correct or incorrect, but what would make it "correct" after running 10 times? If you respond I'll update this and give you an answer.

Edit: The 0.99 figure is how many times we need to repeat an even output until we have a 99% confidence that the number is even. We can state that: $P(\text{even after $n$ repeats}) = 1 - P(\text{odd after $n$ repeats})$ As we just calculated, the probability of it being odd when printing even is $\frac{1}{6}$. We can make a quick table changing the value of $n$, and finding $P(\text{even after $n$ repeats})$:

$n=1$ :  $1 - \frac{1}{6} \approx 0.8333$

$n=2$ : $1 - (\frac{1}{6})^2 \approx 0.9722$

$n=3$ : $1 - (\frac{1}{6})^3 \approx 0.9954$

So after 3 repeats we can be over 99% confident that it truly is an even number.

Comment: Thanks, if the program prints odd we know that the number is odd, but if it prints even, we repeat the program, whenever it prints odd, we conclude the number is odd and stop, otherwise we continue and continue (when it repeats printing "even") then how many times we should continue to get confidence (0.99) that is indeed even.

Comment: Oooh, that makes sense, I'll edit it

Comment: @Ahmad Does that answer your question?

Comment: I don't get how P( odd after n repeats) is $(1/6)^n$, however according to the first calculation if you, like me, call $1/6$ the probability of error in a run. then this probability for $n$ run is $(1/6)^n$ and we want the probability of this error be less than 0.01 ( to be confident with 0.99). in that case I can understand it.

Comment: Also if you check the other answer it uses (1/5) and you used (1/6), so I still don't know which one is correct, otherwise I would vote and accept one of them.

Comment: @Ahmad So we found the probability of it being odd when the machine prints even is $1/6$ right? So in order for it to be odd and the machine prints even twice in a row, the probability is $1/6 * 1/6$ or $(1/6)^2$. It's the same thing for more and more repeats. You are correct in the last bit of your statement. It'd be the same thing as running n repeats until the error chance is below $0.01$.

Comment: @Ahmad The other one is incorrect, I'm very certain. His $1/5$ figure was just taken from the original problem, but that's the chance of an odd number prints as even. We want the probability that a printed number that's even is really odd.

Comment: Yeah I got, you meant `P( odd after n times repeating even)` and you calculated for 1 time and then extended it to n, I got this part, and thank you and I accept it after a short time.

Comment: @Ahmad Like the other answer stated "If the number is odd then after $n$ runs the prob of a success is $1−(1/5)^n$. This is not true, as you stated in your original post, if the output is odd, we have 100% certainty that the number is odd as well.

Comment: @Ahmad Great, glad I could help!

Comment: the question doesn't say the object number is even

Answer (score -2):

if it's even (.5 probability) then prob of success is 1  (an even number always prints even, so if we enter an even number, the result of even is correct with a probability of 1.  Half of numbers are even

if it is odd then prob of success is 4/5.  (in 1/5 of runs we will get the answer 'even', and not have seen the correct result)

If the number is odd then after n runs the prob of a success is $1 - (\frac{1}{5})^n$

after n runs, P of seeing correct answer is

P = $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}(1-(\frac{1}{5})^n)$

to get P = .99, rearrange

$(\frac{1}{5})^n = 1-.99 $

$n \log(\frac{1}{5}) = \log(.01)$

$n = -\log(.01) / \log(5) = 2.9$

so 3 times, since 2.9 times is not possible, you have to exceed this

Comment: When the answer is odd we know the output is true, since if it's an even number it would print out even. We are trying to find the number of times you'd need to repeat an even output to be 99% confident it's really even.

Comment: it doesn't say anywhere that the object number is even.  Also the question literally asks how many times to run the program to get the correct answer, not to 'know' the correct answer.  So I think it's asking 'what is the chance the correct answer has been given after n runs?'  and then furthermore, what does n have to be to attain .99?

Comment: if you run the program twice, then the chance that it will have said 'odd' or 'even' CORRECTLY is .5 + .5(1 - (4/5)^2).
The question does not say that the program ever prints 'even' for an odd number, although I guess failing to print even or odd shows it is odd, although that's no simpler than determining if a number is in fact odd anyway.  That's my take on it - the question tells us little actually.

Comment: Hm, I guess in his comment on my answer he said it was number of even repeats needed so I went with that. Yes the question is pretty unclear.

Comment: If you let run the program $k$ times no matter what the output is , which output counts ? If it is the last one , you can as well just make only one run. The exercise makes only sense, if we assume that we stop if "odd" occurs.

Comment: What is unclear, check the edit! certainly the program prints either odd or even. I thought its certain.

Comment: Also your answer states that the probability of an even number being odd is $1/5$, but this is not correct.

Comment: @Ahmad Do you need to know how many times the program prints even in a row before having a 99% certainty it is even?

Comment: @Caedmon All about this question is confusing! LOL! I wrote correct answer. You don't know what is correct answer, if it prints *odd* at any stage so you get sure it's correct and the number is odd, otherwise you doubt if it's a correct answer and continue, is it clear now?

Comment: int n = 1000000000;
       int evens = 0;
       int evensButOdd = 0;
       
       for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
           int x = (int)(Math.random()*2)+1; // 1 or 2
           if(x == 2){ // If even:
               evens++; // Print even
            }
           else{ // If odd:
               if(Math.random() < (double)1/5){ // If error:
                   evens++; // Print even when odd
                   evensButOdd++;
                }
                else{ // Print odd  
                }
            }
        }

Comment: I ran that code and did 1 billion loops. I got the result that even was printed 599996392 times, and of that 100008581 times it was really odd. This means that 16.668% of the time it printed even it was really odd, exactly my result of $1/6$, not $1/5$.

Comment: @Ahmad yes I think that clarifies. We are just looking for how many times to repeat evens.